# Fix current Mapview and still handle the onTouch Event (GoogleMaps Android)

Tags: android, android-mapview

I'm trying to fix a current Location on my MapView in Android, but still want to handle the onTouch Event.

Background: I've some buttons beside my mapView. If i chosoe "move", the normal behaviour of the mapView is required.

If i choose another button, the current map should be locked, so i can draw something on the map. Therefore i need the onTouch-Event of the map...

my only solution to fix the mapView is to setClickable to false... but when i do this, the onTouch Event will no longer be supported...

How can i make it happen?

Sorry for my bad englisch,

daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having `MapView` processing motion events, don´t call `super.dispatchTouchEvent()` and return true;

Example code:

```
@Override   
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(drawMode){
        //do my drawing here
        return true;
    } else retrun super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);   
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply! I've tried to implement it, but when entering the drawMode, i cannot touch on the mapView anymore... i just want to disable the feature, to move the mapview, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to the drawing in the place I've noted in my answer above. This should be overriding the `dispatchTouchEvent()` of your drawing class, not the `Mapview`.